# How to set up bigtiff?

Tags: c, libtiff

I'm currently trying to saving tif format image with a size larger than 4GB. So I'm trying to set up bigtiff(libtiff 4.1) from bigtiff.org. However, I can't compile it no matter using nmake or vs2012. Using nmake, it have no nmake.opt. Using vs2012, it cannot be compiled into a dll. Errors will be as below:

```
1>tif_codec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFInitPixarLog 
1>tif_codec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFInitZIP 
1>tif_codec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFInitJPEG
```

Does anyone know how to set up bigtiff?

Comment: Maybe post the compiler output?

Comment: 1>tif_codec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFInitPixarLog
1>tif_codec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFInitZIP
1>tif_codec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFInitJPEG

Comment: When compiling with vs2010, these errors above occurred.

Comment: @user3284701 Have you tried googling the error message ("unresolved external symbol")? This is a very common mistake.

Comment: Thank you two for offering help. I've tried several step to fix this but it still cannot work. I just post the original errors here. BTW, does anyone knows how to set up the bigtiff library directly? Maybe with nmake or something else?

Comment: @H2CO3: Alright alright no need to start a big tiff about it

Comment: Then c++ if you'd like me to choose one

Comment: the library is C, removing C++ tag.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: It's my question and it's still about bigtiff

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh... Sorry, I didn't realize the connection :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest building using nmake - I have found that this works better than using Visual Studio (I'm using Visual Studio 2008). I would also suggest downloading the latest version from http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/, the official website for libtiff. This version includes BigTIFF support. This should also include a sample nmake.opt file that you may have to edit to point at your libtiff and libz libraries. If you do not require support for JPEG, ZIP, or Pixar you should be able to disable these in the nmake.opt file. Below are a few lines from the nmake.opt that I use:

```
#
# Uncomment and edit following lines to enable JPEG support.
#
JPEG_SUPPORT = 1
JPEGDIR = C:/libjpeg-turbo
JPEG_INCLUDE = -I$(JPEGDIR)/include
JPEG_LIB = $(JPEGDIR)/lib/jpeg-static.lib

#
# Uncomment and edit following lines to enable ZIP support
# (required for Deflate compression and Pixar log-format)
#
ZIP_SUPPORT = 1
ZLIBDIR = D:/zlib-1.2.7
ZLIB_INCLUDE = -I$(ZLIBDIR)
ZLIB_LIB = $(ZLIBDIR)/build/Release/zlibstatic.lib
```

The missing symbols, if I recall correctly, are found in tif_pixarlog.c, tif_jpeg, and tif_zip respectively. You may want to check for the presence of these files.